# Android: How to make launcher always open the main activity instead of child activity? (or otherwise)

Tags: android, stack, android-activity, task

I have activities A and B. The A is the one with LAUNCHER intent-filter (i.e. the activity that is started when we click the app icon on home screen).

A launches B using `startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class))`.

When the user has the B activity open, and then put my application into the background, and later my application's process is killed, when the user starts my application again, B is opened instead of A.

This caused a force close in my app, because A is the activity that initializes the resources my app needs, and when B tried to access the uninitialized resources, B crashes.

Do you have any suggestions what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you should really have activity B initialize your resources too. But you can put [`android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) in your manifest for activity A to have the launcher always go to that activity.

Comment: Doesn't always do the job apparently. I ended up launch my other activities with: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK while creating intent. 
In your case please try `startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))`

Comment: Sorry, but would be so kind as to explain what you mean by A.this, B.class?  What would the actual syntax be? B is normally expressed as "com.mypackage.FOO" (or whatever I called it in the manifest), and A? I'm not even sure what you mean by A.  I tried ... new Intent(this,  "com.mypackage.FOO".getClass().setFlags  ... but that obviously didn't work (I was just trying it for due diligence sake).

Comment: A.this refers to this in your statement. B.Class refers to the class which you want to invoke.  getclass() will return the runtime class of an object, in this case i think i will return the base class.