# Android onCreate called on Second Activity

Tags: android

Hi I have 2 activities, 
  Activity A and Activity B,
  So its Activity A and on a Button click I go to Activity B. 
  Now I press home button and go and do somany other things. Because of memory issue the task is closed by android. Now when I try to open it again it starts from Activity B. Is this expected?
If yes is there a way to prevent it?

Below is the part of AndroidManifest where both activities are defined
Activity A = MenuActivity, Activity B = AndroidLauncher

```
<activity
            android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Also I am putting the code of onCreate of Activity B

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        int gameType = getIntent().getIntExtra("GAME_TYPE", 0);
        GDXtoAndroidInterface.sharedInstance().activity = this;
        TurnBasedHelper.sharedInstance().listener = this;
        FrameLayout lg=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        lg.addView(initializeForView(new LetterPress(GDXtoAndroidInterface.sharedInstance(),gameType), config));
        busyDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         busyDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
         busyDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
         busyDialog.setCancelable(false);
         showBusy("Setting up..");
         Log.d("MSG", "on create called launcher");
    }
```

Also the reason why I need this is Activity A is like a login screen and Activity B is based on it. Activity B cannot work alone. User has to move from Activity A to Activity B

Thanks

Comment: Please see Android docs on Activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Yes this is expected behavior of application. Your app is just minimized. Every app works this way. As @MarcinOrlowski said check Android docs and Activity lifecycle :) cheers

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I want to always start with Activity A in such situations how to achieve it?

Comment: @PeterM. how to always start with Activity A

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5168915/1231245

Comment: @StefanM. I tried clearTaskOnLaunch = "true" but not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I try to open it again it starts from Activity B. Is this expected?

yes, this is the expected behavior.

when you press the home button (not the "back button") the entire task is sent by default to background, and when re-launching it (from recent tasks screen or the app icon at the home screen)  it coming back by default to foreground with the same stack state as it was. **same behavior applies also if your app was killed by the system while it was in background to preserve memory.  the operating system will store the state of each activity in the stack, an restore it when it need to re-created (see [this post](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html))**

you can think of the home button in relation to Activity like the relation in Windows OS terms as the "minimize" window button,  and back button would be like the "close window" (x) button.

> there a way to prevent it?

assuming you have good reason to do so and break this consistence expected behavior,  you can use all kind of combinations between activity [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and [intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) that will give you the behavior you want..

Comment: I guess what is happening is "same behavior applies also if your app was killed by the system while it was in background to preserve memory. the operating system will store the state of each activity in the stack, an restore it when it need to re-created". I want to prevent it I tried finishOnTaskLaunch on ActivityB and clearTaskOnLaunch on ActivityA. but nothing is working.

Comment: @GeoPaul: post the code of the activities declaration in manifest, and the startActivity() java code of launching activityB.

Comment: @GeoPaul: adding android:launchMode="singleTop" to your AndroidLauncher activity will help.  you can use also android:noHistory="true" on the second activity

Comment: I think android:noHistory was the one I was searching for